# How to use the ARM ADR instruction in Rust?

Tags: assembly, rust, arm

I'm writing an interrupt handler in Rust, and I want to use the `ADR` instruction to get the address of an array containing functions:

```rust
#[naked]
#[export_name = "SVCall"]
unsafe extern "C" fn svcall_isr() -> ! {
    asm!(
        "ldr  r0, [sp, #24]",   // read the PC that was saved before this interrupt happened
        "movs r1, #2",          // store 2 in a reg
        "subs r0, r1",          // subtract 2 from that PC we recovered
        "ldrb r0, [r0]",        // read the byte at that position

        "adr  r1, {0}",         // put address of svcall_table into r1
        "lsls r0, #2",          // multiply svc number by 4 to get byte offset into svcall_table
        "ldr  r2, [r1, r0]",    // load the pointer at offset in svcall_table
        "mov  pc, r2",          // branch into specified svcall routine

        sym SVCALL_TABLE,
        options(noreturn)
    );
}

pub static SVCALL_TABLE: [unsafe extern "C" fn() -> !; 3] = [svcall0_isr, svcall1_isr, svcall2_isr];
```

So that this interrupt handler can call `svcall0_isr`, `svcall1_isr`, or `svcall2_isr` (which are all `unsafe extern "C" fn`s defined elsewhere in the file). However, this `ADR` instruction is not compiling correctly; this is the output of an `objdump`:

```
08000306 <SVCall>:
 8000306:       9806            ldr     r0, [sp, #24]
 8000308:       2102            movs    r1, #2
 800030a:       1a40            subs    r0, r0, r1
 800030c:       7800            ldrb    r0, [r0, #0]
 800030e:       f2af 010c       subw    r1, pc, #12
 8000312:       0080            lsls    r0, r0, #2
 8000314:       580a            ldr     r2, [r1, r0]
 8000316:       4697            mov     pc, r2
 8000318:       defe            udf     #254    ; 0xfe
```

The `ADR` instruction is being transformed into a `SUBW`, and the resulting address is not correct. I also can't seem to find `SVCALL_TABLE` using `objdump`, even if I add a `#[no_mangle]`. Why is this happening, and how do I get the correct address?

Edit: I notice in pure-assembly examples like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59110205/why-do-forward-reference-adr-instructions-assemble-with-even-offsets-in-thumb-co), the table is defined using lines that say `.word`. How do I do this in Rust?

Comment: ADR is a *pseudo-instruction* which means it’s handled by the compiler and the output will not have such instruction since the processor doesn’t have it. Here the compiler decided to use `SUB` and  the symbol is at that location *relative to PC*. If you want an absolute address then `ADR` isn’t suitable.

Comment: @laptou Why do you think that the address is wrong?

Comment: It has not been resolved by the inline assembler.  You could structure your routine differently, if you can send addresses to the inline assembler.  It would be `adr r1, 1f; lsls r0, r0, #2;  ldr pc [r1, r0];  1: table...`.  Table would be a list of routine addresses that follow the assembler code.  This is typical dispatch code.  The table contains absolute addresses.  The `adr` must be pc-relative, so it can not be external.

Comment: @HHK `subw [pc, #12]` will load what is located 12 bytes before the PC, which is at address `0x8000302`. However, a full disassembly of the executable reveals that this address lies in the middle of an instruction in another method (and is not associated with any entry in the symbol table), so it cannot be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using a LDR instruction instead:

```rust
#[naked]
#[export_name = "SVCall"]
unsafe extern "C" fn svcall_isr() -> ! {
    asm!(
        "ldr  r0, [sp, #24]",   // read the PC that was saved before this interrupt happened
        "movs r1, #2",          // store 2 in a reg
        "subs r0, r1",          // subtract 2 from that PC we recovered
        "ldrb r0, [r0]",        // read the byte at that position

        "ldr  r1, ={0}",         // put address of svcall_table into r1
        "lsls r0, #2",          // multiply svc number by 4 to get byte offset into svcall_table
        "ldr  r2, [r1, r0]",    // load the pointer at offset in svcall_table
        "mov  pc, r2",          // branch into specified svcall routine

        sym SVCALL_TABLE,
        options(noreturn)
    );
}
```

Which was resolved correctly in the generated assembly:

```
0800034c <SVCall>:
 800034c:   9806        ldr r0, [sp, #24]
 800034e:   2102        movs    r1, #2
 8000350:   1a40        subs    r0, r0, r1
 8000352:   7800        ldrb    r0, [r0, #0]
 8000354:   4902        ldr r1, [pc, #8]    ; (8000360 <SVCall+0x14>)
 8000356:   0080        lsls    r0, r0, #2
 8000358:   580a        ldr r2, [r1, r0]
 800035a:   4697        mov pc, r2
 800035c:   defe        udf #254    ; 0xfe
 800035e:   bf00        nop
 8000360:   08003aa0    .word   0x08003aa0
```

Which I verified by checking the symbol table, where I can see the `SVCALL_TABLE` located at `0x08003aa0`:

> `08003aa0 l     O .rodata 0000000c _ZN5tasks12SVCALL_TABLE17h255202af4e3eea15E`

Comment: I'm not really sure why LDR worked when ADR did not, though. I would appreciate if someone could explain this.

Comment: `LDR` pseudo-op will accept externals.  It is a full address and takes an instruction plus a lookup.  The `adr` needs to fit in an instruction.  It is PC-relative.  See: [GAS pseudo-ops](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html).  The `LDR` form needs a 'literal pool' as well as the actual table.  `ADR` does not and will execute faster, which might matter for interrupts.  See `adrl` as to why where the location of the label is would matter.  **Note:** A label is not an address and it needs to be defined in the assembler being processed.  The `.word` can be fixed up by a linker.

Comment: Can't you just pass `off0 = const svcall0_isr, off1 = const svcall1_isr, ...` and then use `.word {off0}; .word {off1}...` and make your table inline.  I am not an expert on Rust, but it seems possible to build the table in the assembler to make a standard dispatch.  I guess it is more important if you have swap and 'SVCALL_TABLE' might not be in memory.  Generally the interrupts are pinned to always exist or you have issues.  `svcall1_isr`, etc need to be in the same 'unit' at least for C/C++ linking, but that might not matter for Rust.